# ModalView presented from MasterViewController is no longer Full Screen in iOS 5.1

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a Master/Detail application and have a button on the top right of the MasterViewController in the split view that loads an "Info" view controller using a modal view:

[image: popover in iOS 5.0]

When the button is clicked, the view is loaded, and populates the entire screen in iOS 5.0 and below (this is the behavior that I want):

```
- (IBAction)showAppInfo:(id)sender 
{
    InfoViewController *infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] 
        initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];
    infoViewController.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController: infoViewController animated: YES];
}
```

[image: modalView in iOS 5.0]

However, when I run this in the iOS 5.1 simulator, it no longer populates the entire iPad screen, and only populates what's inside the Master View:

[image: modal view in iOS 5.1]

What can I do to make this InfoViewController populate the entire screen in iOS 5.1 as it did before?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using UIPopoverController, try this

```
InfoViewController *infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] 
    initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];
UIPopoverController *popoverController      =   [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:infoViewController];
    popoverController.popoverContentSize        =   CGSizeMake(500.0, 583.0);
    popoverController.delegate                  =   self;
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:sender.bounds inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Comment: Just curious, is there a way to do this without manually updating the popover dimensions?  Because I assume that I would have to resize it back to normal once the infoview is dismissed.

Comment: if u want a popover controller you should specify its dimensions. Now from your image,what i understood is that u have a master button and when u click on it, u what to show your InfoViewController controller right? so u jus have to do this.

Comment: If that is the case, why was this not needed prior to iOS 5.1?